# Align Xibs in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

How to align all the xibs in storyboard? I am using nearly 10 xibs in single Storyboard. In implementation file we can arrange the code in some manner. Same way is there any option to arrange all these xibs with in storyboard?

Comment: Are you asking about aligning scenes in storyboard?

Well then you can drag and set as per your requirement :)

Comment: A storyboard contains scenes - xibs are something else.